# Component displays a blank screen before data is subscribed from Observable

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I am currently facing an issue with subscribing the data through Observables. Till the time data is being subscribed and stored in a local variable(Object array) for displaying, meanwhile the component loads and thereby displays no data as it is still fetching the data from the back end. I assume the issue is with race conditions(asynchronous), any clue on how to approach this issue?

I am reading Json data which fetches the values in 'ObjectArray' and populates the same as a PrimeNG data table on an angular 2 component.

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="ObjectArray">
    <p-column field="label"></p-column>
 </p-dataTable>
```

Code for subscribing:

```
  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>){
    this.metaData$ = store.select(fromRoot.getMetadata);
  }

  this.metaData$.subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      data.forEach(v => this.ObjectArray.push({...v}));
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can wrap the component in a `<div *ngIf="asyncVariable"></div>` to delay display. You can also add an `<div class="overlay" *ngIf="!asyncVariable">Loading...</div>` if you want a loading screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have three Options Using

Using `ngIf` or using the new `ngIf else` and last and not the least `Router Resolve`

suppose the data your are trying to display is

dataAsync: any;

**Using NgIf**

```
<div *ngIf = "dataAsync">
  {{dataAsync}}
</div>
```

**Using new If else to show a Loading Prompt**

```
  <ng-template #fetching>
    <p>Fetching...</p>
  </ng-template>

  <div *ngIf=" dataAsync; else fetching;">
    <strong>Angular 4 If else Usage - {{dataAsync}}</strong>
  </div>
```

**Router Resolve**

Check out this plunker for Resolve https://plnkr.co/edit/u2qR9J?p=preview

```
@Injectable()
export class Resolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private service: yourService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.service.getdata();
  }
}
```

In routes

```
{ 
    path: 'yourpath',
    component: your Component,
    resolve: {
      resolve: Resolve
    }
```

In component use this on ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.resolve= this.route.snapshot.data['resolve'];
  }
```

And then Display resolve in template.

Please take a look at my page for all such Angular Concepts

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Answer (score 0):

You have several options :

1 - Display a loader while waiting for your data, using `*ngIf` and display the bit of your template when you actually have it.

2 - Use a BehaviourSubject and pass it an initial placeholder value, while waiting for the real one.

3 - Use the async pipe in your component's template like so : `*ngIf="mySubject | async"`